# Using redux with react-hooks without the connect HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Currently, I'm using functional components with hooks but still dispatching my actions with the connect HOC.

I read through the documentation with useDispatch but I'm unsure how to incorporate it in my code. From the examples, they are passing the the action types and payloads inside the component. Would I have to move myOfferActions functions back to the component in order to useDispatch?

MyOffers component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "./MyOffers.scss";
import MyOfferCard from "../../components/MyOfferCard/MyOfferCard";
import { fetchMyOffers } from "../../store/actions/myOffersActions";

const MyOffers = (props) => {
  const myOffers = useSelector((state) => state.myOffers.myOffers);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchMyOffers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="my-offers-main">
      <h1>My offers</h1>
      {myOffers && (
        <div className="my-offer-container">
          {myOffers.map((offer) => (
            <MyOfferCard key={offer.id} offer={offer} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}  
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(null, { fetchMyOffers })(MyOffers);
```

offerActions

```
export const fetchMyOffers = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const userId = localStorage.getItem("userId");
  try {
    const result = await axiosWithAuth().get(`/offers/${userId}`);
    let updatedData = result.data.map((offer) => {
      //doing some stuff
      };
    });
    dispatch(updateAction(FETCH_MY_OFFERS, updatedData));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

offerReducer

```
import * as types from "../actions/myOffersActions";

const initialState = {
  offerForm: {},
  myOffers: [],
};

function myOffersReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_MY_OFFERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        myOffers: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default myOffersReducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need `connect` when using the redux hooks.

You just need to call useDispatch like:
`const dispatch = useDispatch();`

And use the function by providing the object identifying the action:

`dispatch({ type: 'SOME_ACTION', payload: 'my payload'});`

It should be working with `redux-thunk` too (I guess this is what you're using): `dispatch(fetchMyOffers())`

Comment: Is there a way to implement it in such a way that you don't have to wrap everything with `dispatch`? With `connect` you just call `fetchMyOffers()`. Maybe there's a hook that can dispatch the action like this: `const { dispatchFetchMyOffers } = useAction({ fetchMyOffers } );`

Comment: I'm not aware of such hook, at least in react-redux package.

Comment: You can not use a hook without functional component